# Debug breakpoint in Swift Playground?

Tags: swift, xcode6, swift-playground

I'm trying to add a breakpoint in the line # gutter, but no breakpoint is added when I do this in the playground. Is this possible or is there another way to set breakpoints in the playground?

[image]

Comment: The whole notion of a breakpoint is diametrically opposed to the whole notion of what a playground is. - And anyway, what would you do if you could pause at a breakpoint? There's no debugger either!

Comment: I'd like to see the value of the variables at that point.

Comment: In a column to the right of the code, you should see the value of each expression when that line of code is executed.  If it is executed multiple times, you’ll just see "(10 times)”, but you can click the blue dot and see the values over time, either as a graph or a list.

Comment: "I'd like to see the value of the variables at that point" But I just said there is no debugger - so there is no place to see them.

Comment: matt, if you want to see a value of the variable in the playground just specify the variable name.  As an example lets say I want to see the value of foo in the example below, here is how I would do it.  for(i=0;i<10;i++) {dosomething(foo); foo; }

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There's no debugger so you can't add any breakpoints.

Answer (score 4):

Matt, I could not enter code in the comments so here is a better view of using a variable on a line by itself to "debug" it.

```
for index in 1...5  {
    dosomething(foo);
    foo;
}
```

Then you can click the eyeball on the right hand side to see a history of foo as it was modified in the loop.

Comment: C-style for loops are history.

Comment: Clicking the eyeball doesn't work for me (XCode 7.2.1)?

Comment: On the right hand column for each calculation in the playground, there should be a button which gives a popup.  You can toggle different modes.  My example was done in xcode 7.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pause execution of a playground to have a peek at what's going on, you can use `sleep`. The information you can get isn't nearly as granular as what you can get from `lldb`.

To do this, you'll need to add `import Foundation` at the top of your playground.

Then, wherever you want to pause execution, you can add this:

`sleep(10) // 10 second pause...you can make the number whatever you want`

Answer (score 0):

I'm just getting my feet wet in Swift, but I think the playground idea is to show the changing state as if you ran in debug and recorded all the variable changes. There's no actual need for a breakpoint as you can see the state at any "point in time". I think it'll take me a while to get used to it, having used a debugger for > 30 years, but should be quite useful for small bits of isolated test code, especially while I'm learning the language.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can create a swift command line app.
Run these lines in command line in order to create a cli app.

```
mkdir MyCLI
cd MyCLI
swift package init --name MyCLI --type executable
```

Then run it by:

```
swift run MyCLI
```

You can create breakpoints in this app.
I copied code samples from [documentation](https://www.swift.org/getting-started/cli-swiftpm/).